# How to control the default fontsize when creating ttf file using fontforge?

Tags: fontforge

I am deploying fontforge (python script )to create ttf file. I found the fontsize is a little small when using it in android phone.  But I don't know how to tune the default fontsize when creating ttf.

So my question is How to control the default fontsize when creating ttf file using fontforge? Any suggestion will appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The apparent size of a font is determined by the font metrics and the size of the glyphs you draw. Here are my instructions for how to achieve sensible sizing: http://benwhitmore.altervista.org/line-spacing-getting-right/